# How to package an Electron app together with a Node server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have an electron app built using React.js and it relies on a local Node server running on parallel to the App. How can I distribute both products in a single exe so that the Node server made separetely to the Electron app runs at the same time when executing the program?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it. There is a Node process that kicks off the whole app, which you can start your server on. Then the client code is run by whatever you start the BrowserWindow on. Then you can just make requests to localhost and your server should be able to pick them up.

That said, there are some good reasons why you should strongly consider NOT using an actual HTTP server, but using inter-process communication (IPC) instead.

1. Security is an issue — you’re starting a server on a client machine, and if your authentication has any flaws, you’re opening up all your server endpoints to any other process on the client, or even other machines on the local network.
2. Ease - IPC is well supported by Electron so it’s simply easier to develop against.

Comment: I am new to Electron and just read your answer. 

Does this mean I should spawn a child process from the main process and create a node server ?

Comment: No, that already happens for you. See here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model 

When you run Electron, you automatically get 2 processes: `main` (backend, Node.JS) and `renderer` (frontend, React). Electron comes with tools for those 2 processes to talk to each other via IPC: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc

So there's no need to spin off your own process manually.

Comment: So If I want to create a local DB and do some queries and set endpoints 
should I do this on the main process ?

Comment: Yes. Everything aside from rendering the UI can (and probably should) go in the main process.

Comment: I read in a couple of articles that if I am going to establish DB connections and o queries and endpoints 
I should spawn or fork the main process in Electron in favor of performance (not to overload the main process) 

This is one src:
 https://blog.logrocket.com/advanced-electron-js-architecture/#advanced-architecture-proposal

what do you think about this ?

Comment: go for it. I'm no electron expert